# How to make CSS Transition with max-height: none?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

My Html:

```
 <div class="home-intro" id="home-intro">
     <h2>
         <a>Some really long text</a>
     </h2>
</div>
<div id="arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-2x"></i></div>
```

My CSS:

```
.home-intro {
    background: #34373b;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 0 0;
    max-height: 67px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have a javascript that when you click the div `<div id="arrow">` it adds the class `max_marquee` to home-intro, so something like this `<div class="home-intro max_marquee" id="home-intro">`

and the CSS to max_marquee is:

```
.max_marquee {
    max-height: none;
    transition: max-height ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

I want to know how I can make my transition to work when the height expands, I know I need to set a height for the transition to work but I was wondering if there is a workaround because I really never know the height that's why I need it to be max-height: none.

Comment: There's no simple solution to your problem since you cant transition `auto` values, but there are a lot of workarounds. This article explains the issue in depth: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

Answer (score 0):

you have only mistaken the position of the transition propriety that should go in the .home-intro class, also you inverter the time and the transition curve. 
So your css should be like that:

```
.home-intro {
    background: #34373b;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 0 0;
    max-height: 67px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.max_marquee {
    max-height: none;
}
```

you don't need to know the height of the element.

Hope it will help

Comment: Right! ease-in-out and 0.5s are inverted, i haven't noticed it before, try now

Answer (score 0):

you must use `transition` into `.home-intro`

```
.home-intro {
    background: #34373b;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 0 0;
    height: 67px;
    overflow: hidden;
   transition: height ease-in-out 0.5s;

}
.max_marquee {
    height: 200px;

}
```

look at this sample

https://codepen.io/armanab/pen/ZEbXbVR

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but I think I found an answer that allows you to keep `max-height`: using viewport height.

As noted by [Brandon Smith](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/) via [andyvanee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61511474/how-to-make-css-transition-with-max-height-none#comment108847659_61511474), you can't transition `auto` values like `none`. However, the browser does not consider `vh` or `vw` to be autogenerated. Therefore, you can use the following:

```
.max_marquee {
    max-height: 100vh;
    transition: max-height ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

Also, per [ABlue's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61533167/8968816), you must add `transition` to `.home-intro`.

For more reading, read this [helpful guide on viewport concepts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts).